# How can I define a command for lower and upper Riemman integrals with the limits as list?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, expl3, latex3

The command I'm trying to define is the following:

```latex
\lowint{f}[a,b}{\alpha}
```

Expecting:

[image]

When the second argument is empty, the expected result is this:

[image]

I noticed that using `\underline{\int}` produces a weird result. Either way, the code I have is this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\lowint{m D[]{} m}%
{
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {
    \underline{\int} #1\,#3
  }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_lims_clist{ #1 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_low_tl {\clist_item:Nn \l_lims_clist{1}}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_up_tl {\clist_item:Nn \l_lims_clist{2}}

    \underline{\int}
    \limits
    \c_math_subscript_token     { \l_inf_tl }
    \c_math_superscript_token   { \l_sup_tl }
    #1\,#3
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \lowint{f}[a,b]{\alpha}
\]
\end{document}
```

The errors I encounter are the following:

```
Limit controls must follow a math operator.
<argument> ...clist {2}}\underline {\int }\limits 

Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \c_math_subscript_token {\l_inf_tl 

Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c_math_superscript_token {\l_sup_tl
```

I dont understand latex3 code so well and dont know what "normal" syntax can I use inside it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44237/4427

Comment: @egreg It solves the \underline problem, but I would like to understand what is happening with my code, and create a command that does not only put the integral symbol but the whole expression.

Comment: See also the code I added: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711998/4427 Sorry, but your code *can't* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711998/4427 it was possible to solve it without checking if the optional argument is empty.

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\lowerint}{}{\mathop{}\mathpalette\lowerint@\relax\!\int}
\NewDocumentCommand{\upperint}{}{\mathop{}\mathpalette\upperint@\relax\!\int}
\newcommand{\lowerint@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \lowup@{l}{\underline}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\upperint@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \lowup@{r}{\overline}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\lowup@}[3]{%
  % #1 = l (lower) or r (upper)
  % #2 = \underline (lower) or \overline (upper)
  % #3 = math style
  \rlap{%
    \hspace{0.05\wd\z@}%
    \makebox[0.9\wd\z@][#1]{%
      $\m@th#2{%
        \hspace{0.4\wd\z@}%
        \ifx#3\displaystyle\else\hspace{0.1\wd\z@}\fi
        \vphantom{\copy\z@}%
      }$%
    }%
    \hspace{0.05\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\lowint{m D[]{} m}%
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_lims_clist { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_inf_tl {\clist_item:Nn \l_lims_clist {1} }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_sup_tl {\clist_item:Nn \l_lims_clist {2} }

  \lowerint
  ^{\l_sup_tl}
  \sb{\l_inf_tl}
  #1\,\mathrm{d}#3
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
  \lowerint f \,\mathrm{d}\alpha
\]
\[
  \lowint{f}[a,b]{\alpha}
\]
\[
  \lowint{f}{\alpha}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the otput:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why using the complicated syntax `\lowint{f}[a,b]{\alpha}` when you can more simply use `\lowerint_a^b f\,d\alpha`